# c# listview selected item how to

Tags: c#, listview

I have a listview control I would reliably want to get the selected property off. My code

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        label1.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
        label1.Tag = listView1.SelectedItems;
        textBox2.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;  
    textBox3.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
}
```

This works well but when you click the second time or change the selection the program fails with error on the

```
 label1.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
```

How to get this fixed so that it does not fail the second time round.

Comment: What's the error/exception message?

Answer (score 3):

first check if there's any selected item

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if  (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
       return;

    //... rest of code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have Understand Your Question That You Want To Get The Selected Item Name/Text.

You Can Use `FocusedItem.Text`/`Name`

```
label3.Text = listView1.FocusedItem.Text;
```

Instead of using `listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text` because it can used only be Once